# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUES' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp2017\www\PHPCMS\categories.php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and sql. I am just trying to build a blog and I am getting error message when I try to run through localhost. I am using php version 7 and sql version 5.7. 
I am getting error on line 26 which is this one

please help me out. many thanks

```
<?php require_once("Include/db.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("Include/sessions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("Include/functions.php"); ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    $Category=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["Category"]);
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$CurrentTime=time();
//$DateTime=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$CurrentTime);
$DateTime=strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",$CurrentTime);
$DateTime;
$Admin="Admin";
if(empty($Category)){
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="All Fields must be filled out";
    Redirect_to("categories.php");

}elseif(strlen($Category)>99){
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Too long Name for category";
    Redirect_to("categories.php");

}else{

        global $linkDB;
        $Query="INSERT INTO category(datetime,name,creatorname)"
        VALUES('$DateTime','$Category','$Admin');
        $Execute=mysqli_query($Query);
        if($Execute){
            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]="Category Added Successfully";
            Redirect_to("categories.php");
}
else{
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Catrgory failed to Add";
            Redirect_to("categories.php");
}
}

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Manage Categories</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/adminstyles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h1>My First Blog</h1>

                <ul id="side_Menu" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

                <li><a href="admin_dashboard.php">

                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>&nbsp; Dashboard</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>&nbsp; Add New Post</a></li>

                <li class="active"><a href="categories.php"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-tag "></span>&nbsp; Categories</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; Manage Admins</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>&nbsp; Comments</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer"></span>&nbsp; Live Blog</a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp; Logout</a></li>

        </ul>


        </div> <!--Ending of Side area-->
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <h1>Manage Categories</h1>
        <div><?php echo Message();
                echo SuccessMessage();
                ?>
        <div>
        <form action="categories.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="categoryname">Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Category" id="catrgoryname" placeholder="Name">
        </div>  
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Add New Category">
        </fieldset>
        <be>
</form>


              </div>  <!--ending of main area-->


        </div> <!--ending of row-->

        <!--end of container -->

        <div id="Footer">
        <hr><p>Blog by A R Khalid ¦ &copy;Media Shark</p>
        <a style="color: white; text-decoration: none; pointer; font-weight:bold;">

        <div style="height: 10px; background:#27AAE1;"></div>

    </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line for query for insert:

```
$Query="INSERT INTO category(datetime,name,creatorname)"
        VALUES('$DateTime','$Category','$Admin');
```

should be:

```
$Query="INSERT INTO category(datetime,name,creatorname)
        VALUES('$DateTime','$Category','$Admin')";
```

or:

```
$Query="INSERT INTO category(datetime,name,creatorname)".
        "VALUES('$DateTime','$Category','$Admin')";
```

Comment: Syntax error as you forgot a closing double quote `"`